# Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a valid json (any json string) string and trying to convert it to Dataset but Newtonsoft.Json failed to do so.

Json text:

```
  {"root": {
  "Item": [
    {
      "Name": "Super Mario Bros",
      "Count": "14",
      "Price": "29,99",
      "Comment": "-No Comment-",
      "Artist": "N/A",
      "Publisher": "Nintendo",
      "Genre": "Video Games",
      "Year": "1985",
      "ProductID": "001"
    },
    {
      "Name": "The Legend of Zelda",
      "Count": "12",
      "Price": "34,99",
      "Comment": "-No Comment-",
      "Artist": "N/A",
      "Publisher": "Nintendo",
      "Genre": "Video Games",
      "Year": "1986",
      "ProductID": "002"
    }
  ]
}
}
```

Code:

```
var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsonText);
```

Error:

> Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path 'root', line 1, position 9.

Edit 1:

> user can pass any type of json and i need to convert it to DataSet 
>   for the above example "root" element can contain any other property
>   like "child1":"val1", "child2":"val2" and so forth. so, the output
>   dataset will contain 2 tables namse root(should have one rows of
>   properties 1 and 2) and item(should have 2 rows of type name,count,price
>   etc).

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu, how? i am not getting you, could you please post the code please.

Comment: Yes, you're missing the wrapping, if this is a dictionary, then you need to wrap the whole thing in `{...}`. There is no such thing as a standalone `"key": value` thing in JSON; it has to be part of a dictionary/object. In other words, **what you've posted is not valid JSON**.

Comment: Are you sure you want a `DataSet`? That is a heavy object if all you need is the `Item` array.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, question edited and json fixed.

Comment: After fixing the json, do you still get the same error?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen no, it's working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Json you showed is invalid.

It should look like this, to be load to the `DataSet`:

```
{
  "Item": [
    {
      "Name": "Super Mario Bros",
      "Count": "14",
      "Price": "29,99",
      "Comment": "-No Comment-",
      "Artist": "N/A",
      "Publisher": "Nintendo",
      "Genre": "Video Games",
      "Year": "1985",
      "ProductID": "001"
    },
    {
      "Name": "The Legend of Zelda",
      "Count": "12",
      "Price": "34,99",
      "Comment": "-No Comment-",
      "Artist": "N/A",
      "Publisher": "Nintendo",
      "Genre": "Video Games",
      "Year": "1986",
      "ProductID": "002"
    }
  ]
}
```

Code:

```
var dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsonText);
var table = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

Comment: json is valid, actually the json is dynamic in my case so user can load any type of json.
root can have any other property as well apart from the item array. how can i deal with the situation like this.

Comment: @A_Name_Does_Not_Matter - Your json is invalid. It cannot start with literal. See [JSON](https://www.json.org/). Use any validator online to test.

Comment: @A_Name_Does_Not_Matter - _any type_? Well, wait for the artificial intelligence. Or write your own logic to handle such situations.

Comment: yes, json missing syntax but should contain the "root" node, updating question for more clarification.

Comment: Why was this answer selected as the solution? It doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 9):

It is not working because the JSON object representing the `DataSet` is not at the root level of the JSON.  In your JSON, it is inside a *property* called `root`, which is inside another wrapper object.  So you will need to take that outer object into account when you deserialize.  You can either define a wrapper class and deserialize into that:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("root")]
    public DataSet DataSet { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
DataSet ds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(json).DataSet;
```

([Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RdyPzA))

Or, if you don't want to make a class, you can instead deserialize into a `JObject`, navigate down to the `root` property and then materialize it to a `DataSet` from there:

```
DataSet ds = JObject.Parse(json)["root"].ToObject<DataSet>();
```

([Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6cTSpf))

Comment: what we will do in case of third party json?, if we do not know `json's first node name`, "root", in this example....

Comment: @biryaz  If you don't know the name of the first node, you can do this instead: `DataSet ds = JObject.Parse(json).Properties().First().Value.ToObject<DataSet>();`  [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u3BDpV)

Comment: thanks, joining this with the answer of @dbc `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786123/xmlnodeconverter-can-only-convert-json-that-begins-with-an-object` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

just add `[]` while stringifying the object:

```
JSON.stringify([this.YourModel])
```