# XmlNodeConverter can only convert JSON that begins with an object. Path '', line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Getting issue with below code

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument xd1 = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xd1 = (System.Xml.XmlDocument)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(customJsonArrayData.ToString(), currentSheetName); //getting issue here.
DataSet jsonDataSet = new DataSet();
jsonDataSet.ReadXml(new System.Xml.XmlNodeReader(xd1));
```

I had gone through [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786123/xmlnodeconverter-can-only-convert-json-that-begins-with-an-object), but do we have any short simple answer than given in that post.

Comment: Did the solution work in your project?If not,could you share `customJsonArrayData.ToString()` and `currentSheetName`?

Answer (score 0):

For XmlNodeConverter can only convert JSON that begins with an object,you could add the object manually like below:

```
xd1 = (System.Xml.XmlDocument)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode("{\"root \":"+yourJsonString+"}","root");
```